# Google Cloud DataLab + BigQuery: how to set region/zone/location

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, kaggle

I'm using the Datalab for a Python notebook that loads data from Cloud Storage into BigQuery [basically following this example](https://github.com/googledatalab/notebooks/blob/master/tutorials/BigQuery/Importing%20and%20Exporting%20Data.ipynb).

I then saw that my original data in the Cloud Storage bucket is in the EU (eu-west3-a), the VM that executes the Datalab is in the same region, but the final data in BigQuery is in the US.

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44436759/how-do-i-set-the-data-location-of-a-bigquery-table-over-the-api?rq=1) I tried setting the location for the dataset in code, but did not work. This is because there is no such option defined in the [Datalab.Bigquery Python module](http://googledatalab.github.io/pydatalab/datalab.bigquery.html#datalab.bigquery.Dataset).

**So my question is:** How do I set the location (zone and region) for the BigQuery dataset and its containing tables?

This is my code:

```
# data: https://www.kaggle.com/benhamner/sf-bay-area-bike-share/data
%%gcs read --object gs://my_bucket/kaggle/station.csv --variable stations

# CSV will be read as bytes first
df_stations = pd.read_csv(StringIO(stations))
schema = bq.Schema.from_data(df_stations)
# Create an empty dataset
#bq.Dataset('kaggle_bike_rentals').create(location='europe-west3-a')
bq.Dataset('kaggle_bike_rentals').create()

# Create an empty table within the dataset
table_stations = bq.Table('kaggle_bike_rentals.stations').create(schema = schema, overwrite = True)

# load data directly from cloud storage into the bigquery table. the locally loaded Pandas dataframe won't be used here
table_stations.load('gs://my_bucket/kaggle/station.csv', mode='append', source_format = 'csv', csv_options=bq.CSVOptions(skip_leading_rows = 1))
```

**Update:** Meanwhile I manually created the dataset in the BigQuery Web-UI and used it in code without creating it there. Now an exception will be raised if the dataset is not existing thus forbidding to create a one in code that will result in default location US.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried bq.Dataset('[your_dataset]').create(location='EU')?

Comment: Indeed, but this option is not existent. Seems that the client libraries are not fully implemented.

Comment: If you feel like this feature is missing, you can file a feature request via https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers.

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery locations are set on a dataset level. Tables take their location based on the dataset they are in.

Setting the location of a dataset at least outside of Datalab:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
bigquery_client = bigquery.Client(project='your_project')

dataset_ref = bigquery_client.dataset('your_dataset_name')
dataset = bigquery.Dataset(dataset_ref)
dataset.location = 'EU'

dataset = bigquery_client.create_dataset(dataset)
```

Based on the code snippet from here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/datasets